# Web API sending byte array from picture gives 404

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, web-applications, asp.net-web-api2

i need help with my WebAPI. I have the following in the server :

```
 [System.Web.Http.HttpGet]
        public HttpResponseMessage Recognize(byte[] img)
        { 

        }
```

And my client requests :

```
  using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {

                client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost/MP.Business.Implementation.FaceAPI/");
                using (var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, client.BaseAddress))
                {
                    var imageStream = new ByteArrayContent(pic);
                    var multi = new MultipartContent();
                    multi.Add(imageStream);

                    //   var response = client.
                    HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync("api/Recognition/Recognize/"+ multi).Result;
```

The breakpoint is not hit and i get 404.However if i send this request :

```
 HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync("api/Recognition/Recognize/").Result;
```

the breakpoint is hit and obviously i get error inside , because the byte[] is null(but at least it hits) . What do i do wrong ?

Comment: 99% sure this should be a POST not a GET

Comment: Because you're posting the data it should be client.PostAsync